# Multiple comboboxes depended source

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

In a caliburn.micro MVVM project I have multiple comboboxes. They are bound to a property that calculates values to show in the dropdown.

```
public string SelectedComboBox1
{
   get { return RefObject.Value1; }
   set { 
      RefObject.SetValue1(value); 

      NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ComboBox2Source);
      NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedComboBox2);
   }
}
public List<string> ComboBox1Source
{
   get { return CalculateComboBox1(); }
}
public string SelectedComboBox2
{
   get { return RefObject.Value2; }
   set { RefObject.SetValue2(value); }
}
public List<string> ComboBox2Source
{
   get { return CalculateComboBox2(RefObject.Value1); }
}
```

The problem is when I set value on ComboBox1 and call SelectedComboBox1, the function RefObject.SetValue1 sets the Value2 as a default.

So I tried to call notify changed on the source and value. The source do get updated, but when it does it calls the SelectedComboBox2 with null parameter. That sets the value to null.

Program flow:

- All sources and values are set correctly.
- ComboBox1 has value "combobox1 value1" and ComboBox2 has value
  "combobox2 value1" Changes ComboBox1 to lets say "combobox1 value2"
- SelectedComboBox1 is called and the RefObject.SetValue1 is called.
  This function changes Value1 and **also Value2** on the RefObject.
  RefObject.Value2 now has value "combobox2 value2", a value that not
  exists in the ComboBox2Source at init().
- I Call NotifyOfPropertyChange for ComboBox2Source, it's get updated and now the value of "combobox2 value2" exists in the source, but WPF calls SelectedComboBox2 set with value = null (guessing it's because it don't know it change since we haven't notified about it)

If I call NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedComboBox2); first, then the value does not exist in the source, and therefore cannot be set.

What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

> SelectedComboBox1 is called and the RefObject.SetValue1 is called.
>   This function changes Value1 and **also Value2** on the RefObject.

At this point, I'd ensure that your new item is in the collection, essentially enforcing that the value for `SelectedComboBox2` is never set to anything that is not in `ComboBox2Source`.

So somewhere in `RefObject.SetValue1`, in the part that also changes `RefObject.Value2`, I'd include something like this before setting `RefObject.Value2`:

```
if (!ComboBox2Source.Contains(value))
{
    ComboBox2Source.Add(value)
}
```

Comment: But to notify that I have updated the ComboBox2Source i would have to do NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ComboBox2Source). And thats mean it would behave like it does today (?)

Comment: Well, if the new value is in `ComboBox2Source`, you should be able to set `SelectedComboBox2` without it returning `null`? Could you post more of your code, e.g., `RefObject` and the calculation methods?